# How I can use a WindowsSymLinks from Ubuntu's SMB share?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, sharing, smb

I have a set of Windows SymLinks that give a path to another network share. Those links are working properly for Windows and on Windows' shares. Now I placed all those SymLinks on Ubuntu SMB share and I can't see it from Windows. I don't need to use it from Ubuntu, I just want to Ubuntu SMB-server only shown me it. How can I solve this trouble?

Comment: Can you show the composition of the "symlink". A typical samba link on Ubuntu will look like "smb://10.36.6.23/folder".

Comment: Look, I want to open the windows-created symlink from windows, and store this symlink on ubuntu SMB-share.

Comment: Originally, the symlink have a right path to another windows SMB share (for ex. "\\192.168.0.10\share"). If I watch this windows SymLink from ubuntu, it marked as a broken and contains the string like this: "/??/UNC/192.168.0.10/share". But I don't care, how it looks on ubuntu. I just need to use this symlink from any windows host. How I can see it on Ubuntu SMB share from Windows Host?

Comment: I really don't understand what it is you want. I will bow out at this stage.

Comment: Ok, I'll try another way. Look, I have WinSRV, WinPC1 and WinPC2.
WinPC1 is usual user's PC with Windows.
WinPC2 is another PC with Windows. It contains the share, available by path "\\WinPC2\share".
WinSRV is windows server that contains the share, available by path "\\WinSRV\share".
Also, \\WinSRV\share contains a symlink "symWin" to path "\\WinPC2\share". And I can access path \\WinSRV\share\symWin and I will see the content of \\WinPC2\share.
So, this is initial conditions.

Comment: Next step. 
I need to replace my WindowsSRV with UbuntuPC, that have installed Ubuntu OS.
I add an UbuntuPC, that contains the share, available by path "\\UbuntuPc\share".
Now I need to place symWin to "\\UbuntuPC\share" so it kept working for WinPC1. In other words, when I access the path "\\UbuntuPC\share\symWin" from WinPC1 I need to see the content of "\\WinPC2\share".
So, at first I copied \\WinSRV\share\symWin to \\UbuntuPC\share\symWin. Is it right? ))

Comment: In fact, the following occurs: 
1. when I access \\UbuntuPC\share\ from WinPC1, I see nothing. There is no symWin. 
2. when I look inside UbuntuPC (under Ubuntu OS), I see that symWin is there, but it marked like as broken symLink, that contains the string "/??/UNC/WinPC2/share".

In total, I need to get access to \\UbuntuPC\share\symWin from WinPC1.
In another words, I need to view the content of \\WinPC2\share when I access the \\UbuntuPC\share\symWin.

I tried to explain so that it is clear. Thank you in advance!